# What is the best way to using BLoC, one BLoC per screen or one BLoC per part of screen?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm currently developing the Flutter application using BLoC with flutter_bloc and I wonder what is the best way to manage the state using BLoC. In my situation, there're two main separate parts on the same screen. So, I end up created two BLoC for each part of screen as I tried with one BLoC first and it didn't work well. Because of the state trigger the loading for both part of the screen. What's the recommendation for this situation. Should I go for one BLoC per screen with a better-designed state to make it not reload every part or should I go for one BLoC per dynamic part of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to your project be scaleable, use bloc per feature not for per screen.